# Why can't I protect the "Password Setting" in System Preferences

Tags: macos, security, passwords

I'm a Linux user who's not experienced with issues pertaining to Macs, so perhaps I would otherwise understand and accept this problem, but it doesn't make sense to me.

My wife occasionally allows our 14-year-old son to use her MacBookPro (El Capitan).  It appears that he goes to System Preferences->Security & Privacy then unchecks the "Require password" and, for good measure, also sets the time from "immediately" to "8 hours" in case my wife re-checks the option.

When I click the lock at the bottom left and access the "Advanced" options, I check (ie enable) "Require an administrator password to access system-wide preferences."  I would expect that setting would protect that "System Preferences" dialog, but it doesn't.  Even with the "Require an administrator password..." enabled, anyone on the computer can disable the  "Require Password" setting.

Perhaps I don't understand the setting, but is it possible that he found another setting that overrides the password setting?  If it was my computer, I might open a terminal window and set the access privileges to System Preferences to 000, but that would be too obscure for my wife on her computer, so I'm looking for an easier option.

Comment: "anyone on the computer can"... no, anyone with an admin account can. Don't give him an admin account or let him know the credentials of one. By default, all admin accounts are sudoers & can undo anything any other admin does...

Comment: What's the point of the padlock icon, then?  It implies (and I think I remember it working this way once before) that the page must be unlocked to make changes.  Opening the padlock requires the password, which, to my non-Mac mind, should secure the dialog from unauthorized changes.  However, the lock status makes no difference in the ability to disable passwords.

Comment: It's not really just that one option, there are many others that aren't locked to a logged-in admin user even with the padlock closed, but giving your kid access to an admin account is still not best practise. Give him his own parentally-controlled account, change your admin passwords & take charge. Note, don't put parental controls on an admin account or it will no longer be an admin account, but I don't think it actually warns you of that.

Comment: Late thought... that particular control is not a system-wide control,. it's account-specific, so that's the main reason it's not locked to an already logged-in admin

Comment: I have made a "kids" account on her computer, but the problem is that she will likely continue to, on the rare occasions she will lend her computer to one of the kids, just turn the computer over to them.

Comment: (I guess I can't edit my own comment?)

Do I understand you correctly, that for an administrative user, even when a page includes a padlock that _does_ require a password to open, the state of the padlock has no effect on the page?  Then what is the point of requiring a password or displaying the padlock?

Comment: As any admin user would have the right to unlock it... your guess is as good as mine, really - but it still remains that the padlock is for system-wide prefs, & that particular pref just happens to be per-user.